# Usar Sintaxe Alternativa muda o desempenho?

Tags: php, desempenho

Usar a [Sintaxe Alternativa para estruturas de controle](https://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators) traz enormes mudanças na quantidade de linhas de code de um projeto, mas existe algum mudança em desemepenho?

Comment: Dificilmente ...

Comment: Não ⊂(▀¯▀⊂) ⊂(▀¯▀⊂)

Comment: Faz diferença mesmo é na legibilidade do código. Se você usar o operador ternário para controle de fluxo, o código fica bem menos legível.

Answer (score 1):

Dificilmente isso faria algum efeito no desempenho. O PHP e outras linguaguens de script já perdem desempenho(comparada as compiladas) por serem interpretadas. Desempenho deve ser o quando encontrar algum gargalo no sistema(lentidão), mas primeiro é necessario mensurar isso, senão como vai saber?

Answer (score 0):

A quantidade de script a mais é muito pequena (pode se dizer insignificante), então dessa forma o processamento será rápido e sem visíveis mudanças.